# Show/Hide Multiple Divs depend upon screen angular 2

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ng2-bootstrap

I want to use some buttons to show/hide multiple divs using angular2

The page will initially show all divs. when the small screen i hide all div and then separate buttons to show a particular div while hiding the rest.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<div class="buttons">
<a class="button" id="showdiv1">Div 1</a>
<a class="button" id="showdiv2">Div 2</a>
<a class="button" id="showdiv3">Div 3</a>
</div>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xlg-4 col-xl-5 col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 hidden-sm-down">
  </div>

   <div class="col-xlg-4 col-xl-5 col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 hidden-sm-down">
  </div>

   <div class="col-xlg-4 col-xl-5 col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 hidden-sm-down">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried yourself using Angular 2? The code you have posted is only HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `@HostListener` along with the `resize` event to determine the viewport's width. Then set assign a property with this value in your component which you can then supply to an `ngIf*` in your HTML template.

```js
import { Component, HostListener, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component()

export class AppComponent { 

  windowWidth: number = window.innerWidth;

  //initial values, The window object may still be undefined during this hook, let me know if that's the case and we'll figure out a better hook for the initial value
  ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
  }

  //if screen size changes it'll update
  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  resize(event) {
      this.windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
  }

}
```

```html
<!-- Then any HTML element you wish to toggle apply the *ngIf directive as so: -->

<div *ngIf*="windowWidth > 800">content</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much. how to show particular div click event

Comment: Like so: `<div (click)="myFunction()">` Then define `myFunction()` inside your component.